# show a list of Maximal number of renting

Tags: sql-server

Hi guys got a question and would like your help to solve it I have a tricky query asking me of displaying a list of vehicles make 'most popular model holds the maximal number of rent'?????

sql-server

```
CAR_SERIAL_NO     MODEL                          MAKE                           
---------------- ------------------------------ --------------
1234              Turbo                          Porche                                
5678              Zafera                         Opel                                 
9012              Crawn                          Toyota                                   
3456              M5                             Bmw                                            
7890              Cabrio                         Bmw  

CAR_REGSTRATE_NO CAR_SERIAL_NO  
---------------- -------------
XV98CR               1234                          
CXER73               5678                     
098X44               9012                      
89EE43               3456                     
09KK33               7890   

CONTRACT_NO   CAR_REGSTRATE_NO   CLIENT_ID      START      END
------------- ----- -----------  --- ------  ----------- -----------
2344              XV98CR         45623        01-DEC-02  20-FEB-03                 
2335              CXER73         23344        12-OCT-02  12-DEC-03                  
3333              098X44         22442        10-OCT-02  15-OCT-03                 
5555              89EE43         77774        10-FEB-13  15-FEB-03                
6666              09KK33         33223        22-JUN-12  10-JAN-03
```

Comment: Please don't repost questions, fix your original question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Select all models, cross join with vehicles and cross join with rents, group by models with count(*) - let's call this subquery table T. Having this you can ask for maximum over column containing count and filter T to display only max.

Comment: Hi Adrian, is there anyway I can make subquery but if I ask in subquery and how do I use max over the column containing count??

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't list your required results, I've made my best guess. If you need something different you must edit you question and add your desired output.

Anyway, this might work:

```
with HireDetails as
(
  select CAR_REGSTRATE_NO
    , Hires = count(1)
    , HireDays = sum(datediff(dd, START, [END]))
  from Hire
  group by CAR_REGSTRATE_NO
)
select c.MAKE
  , c.Model
  , c.CAR_SERIAL_NO
  , r.CAR_REGSTRATE_NO
  , hd.HireDays
  , hd.Hires
from Registration r
  inner join Car c on r.CAR_SERIAL_NO = c.CAR_SERIAL_NO
  left join HireDetails hd on r.CAR_REGSTRATE_NO = hd.CAR_REGSTRATE_NO
order by hd.HireDays desc
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39c71/6). You'll note that I changed some of the dates at the `START` date was a decade greater than the `END` date. Again, you need to update your question with more details if this is incorrect.

I've aggregated the hire details as it's not a reasonable assumption that a car would only be hired once, even though this is the case in your sample data.